# How to control ScrollView, that doesn't be repreated again and again

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, scroll, scrollview

Do you know, how to control the ScrollView, so they do not repeat. For example I have 5 pictures (like the added figure), they should be viewable from 1-5 and it should stop right after the last picture, at the same time it should be able to scroll back and stop right after the first picture. All in all it should only be able to go from 1-5 without repeating after 5th picture and before 1st.

The problem right now is, that it scroll further after 5th, so it begins from 1st picture again, and the other way around when it scroll back to 1st picture it keep going to 5th and so on.

The code that I used for this is: 
["InfinitePagingView"](https://github.com/caesarcat/InfinitePagingView/blob/master/Classes/InfinitePagingView.m/) page!.

Disabled scroll:

```
   scrollEnabled = NO;
```

[image]

What I want to know is, if I am able to stop scrolling right after 5th picture, but it should only be enable to do that on the right side. So is there any codes like: "scrollEnable right = NO & scrollEnable left = NO". If not, which code can I use.

Advance thanks

Comment: maybe you shouldn't use an infinite scrolling view when you don't want infinite scrolling...

Comment: @jimpic yes you are right `Neruja Joseph` you should use simple `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you want infinite scrolling on the right side, but not on the left?  You need to customize the `InfinitePagingView`, that you are using. Look in the code, especially the method `scrollView:didScroll` and disable it for the left side.

That is not a default behaviour, so there is not a simple property to set. But don't you think this is a strange behaviour? If you scroll right and go over the 5th picture, than you are at the 1st one again and you cannot scroll to the left anymore? Although you just came from that place?

If you don't want any infinite scrolling just use a default scrollView!

Answer (score 0):

I have using following Code to display 5 UIButtons in Scrollview it works for as you want.you can use it for 5 pictures Check it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
 {

UIScrollView *scrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 407, 320, 80)]; 
[self.view addSubview:scrollview];
int i;
int spacex = 5;
int spacey=5;
for ( i = 0; i <5; i++) 
{   
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(spacex, spacey, 115, 45)];
    btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]; 
    [btn setTitleColor: [UIColor blackColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    spacex = spacex + 120;
    [scrollview addSubview:btn];
}
  scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollview.frame.size.height*(i+2) , scrollview.frame.size.height); 
 [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

You can changed it according to your requirments.hope it works for you.Thanks.